# Refining a list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of messy equations, called `question`:

```
question = {a == a1, b == b1 && c == c1, d == 0, e == e1, k1 == k1, n==n1@@m1==m1};
```

I want to refine it as:

```
answer = {a == a1, b == b1, c == c1, e == e1, n==n1};
```

There are several things to do to obtain `answer`:

1. replace `&&` with `,`
2. delete `k1==k1` and `m1==m1`
3. delete `d==0`

How can I get the list `answer`?

I tried several rules but with no success. For example, `&& -> ,` does not work, while `Equal->Rule` works (though this is not used in my question).

I searched old answers in the MSE and found some answers for deleting `d==0`, for example, however, the answers are not working in my case.

Comment: `List @@ (And @@ question)` should do for converting to a full list, and `d == 0` is removable with `DeleteCases[]`.

Comment: @JMcomputer-less: Your proposal produces: {a == a1, b == b1, c == c1, d == 0, e == e1, n == m1 == m1}, which is not the same as the list `answer`. For deleting elements, DeleteCases[%, _ == 0] works for me: {a == a1, b == b1, c == c1, e == e1, n == m1 == m1}, but I still do not have the right `answer`.

Comment: No, of course not; I only gave you something to start with.

Comment: @JMComputer-less: You are right and you gave me a good starting point. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[List @@ And @@ question, Equal[_, 0] | Equal[0, _]]
List @@ And @@ question /. Equal[_, 0] | Equal[0, _] :> Sequence[]
Flatten[question /. And -> List /. Equal[_, 0] | Equal[0, _] | True :> Sequence[]]
```

all give

> {a == a1, b == b1, c == c1, e == e1, n == n1}

Comment: A very nice code. I have two related questions: `Equal[_,0]` picks those equations in which `zero` is placed on the right hand side only. Any other way to recognize both the right and left side `zeros` because I cannot control computer outputs? Second, I still get `{a == a1, b == b1, c == c1, e == e1, n == m1 == m1}` in all three cases, where `n==m1==m1`, which is not what I want. Is this my computer's problem? I use `Mathematica 10`.

Comment: @Tugrul, `Alternatives[]` is what you seem to want: `( _ == 0) | (0 == _)` for covering the expressions equated to zero.

Comment: @JMComputer-less: Yes, it works. I have been struggling to get the output what @kglr provided above. My computer is still giving me `n==m1==m1` as an element of the list. I quit Kernel and re-start but the problem still remains. Is there any other way to fix this problem? Any idea?